# updating the table using recordset

Tags: vb6

I have a recordset `rcdDNE`. I want to update my reclamation by making some conditions with my existing recordset. But my table is not updating. Can you guys tell me where I am doing wrong?

```
    Dim lngRecCount As Long

frmDNELoad.lblStatus.Caption = "Updating records in Reclamation Table..."
frmDNELoad.Refresh
CqDate = Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")

Set rcdreclamation = New ADODB.Recordset
With rcdreclamation
    .ActiveConnection = objConn
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM T_DATA_reclamation"
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open
End With

rcdDNE.MoveFirst

Do Until rcdDNE.EOF
With cmdDNEFRC
    .ActiveConnection = objConn
    .CommandText = "update t_data_reclamation set ClaimStatus = 'C',DateClosed = 'CqDate', Audit_LastUpdated = 'CqDate', Audit_UserAdded = 'SYSTEM' where RTProvided = '" & rcdDNE("AccountNbr") & "'"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
End With

rcdDNE.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless its something you forgot to put in your sample code, You are missing a call to the `Execute` function inside your Command object's with block.

```
With cmdDNEFRC
  .ActiveConnection = objConn
  .CommandText = "update t_data_reclamation set ClaimStatus = 'C',DateClosed = 'CqDate', Audit_LastUpdated = 'CqDate', Audit_UserAdded = 'SYSTEM' where RTProvided = '" & rcdDNE("AccountNbr") & "'"
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .Execute 'dont forget execution 
End With
```

Also when writing data to the table, using Connection objects `BeginTrans` and `CommitTrans` function is recommended, just in case something has to go wrong when writing the data you don't end up with data inconsistencies.